# HDInsight Hive log location

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to create an external table in Hive using Azure HDInsight with PowerShell (cmdlet Invoke-Hive) but it's failing with the below error in stderr:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/C:/apps/dist/hive-0.13.0.2.1.15.1-1234/conf/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.15.1-1234/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hbase-0.98.0.2.1.15.1-1234-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
OK
Time taken: 1.256 seconds
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureExce
ption java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.)
```

So I want to do exactly as the description says and check the original exception, but I can't seem to find the full log anywhere. Can someone point me to the correct location of the full stack trace?

EDIT: I noticed this error occurs only when there is an Append Blob in my external table location directory. Doesn't the Append Blob work together with HDInsight Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDInsight currently only supports Block blobs...

The hive logs can be found in the user folder of main Azure storage account for your HDInsight cluster.
EX:

```
<StorageAccount>/user/<username>/<jobid>
```

If this is not enough you can also remote into the cluster and check the job logs directly from the head node using the web portal pre-installed there.